# KnockoutJS observableArray binding not being notified of update when using foreach

Tags: knockout.js

I have an issue whereby if I use a foreach binding with an observableArray, I am not seeing the changes made to the observableArray reflect on the screen.

The binding looks like this:

```
<div data-bind="foreach: items">
  <p>
    <input data-bind="value: name" />
  </p>
  <p>Name: <span data-bind="text: name"></span></p>
  <br />
</div>
```

The observableArray looks like this:

```
this.items = ko.observableArray([
    { name: 'Person 1', role: 'Sales' },
    { name: 'Person 2', role: 'Accounts' },
    { name: 'Person 3', role: 'Admin' }
  ]);
```

Here is a JSFiddle to illustrate the problem:
https://jsfiddle.net/ue3opdd2/2/

The HTML is split in 2 sections using a horizontal break. In section 1 is a binding which uses an observable. If you modify the text box, you see the change reflected in the span element below. This is working.

In section 2 is the exact same principal, but using an observableArray and a foreach binding. If you change the value in the "Person 1" text box for example, I would expect to see this change reflected in the span element below, but it doesn't work (it stays as "Name: Person 1").

I have put a debug output at the bottom of the screen and I do not see the values for the observableArray update in there either.

The main difference I can see is that the observableArray is a "complex type". By this I mean that each element is made up of an object containing a name and a role. Would this make a difference?

Can anyone help me to get this working please?

Comment: The items in the array need to be observable as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`observableArray` doesn't automatically make its contents observable:

> Key point: An observableArray tracks which objects are in the array,
>   not the state of those objects
>
> Simply putting an object into an observableArray doesn’t make all of
>   that object’s properties themselves observable. Of course, you can
>   make those properties observable if you wish, but that’s an
>   independent choice. An observableArray just tracks which objects it
>   holds, and notifies listeners when objects are added or removed.

(From http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observableArrays.html)

If you update your view model and make `name` observable, your code should work the way you expect:

```
var ViewModel = function () {
  this.item = ko.observable('Test name');

  this.items = ko.observableArray([
    { name: ko.observable('Person 1'), role: 'Sales' },
    { name: ko.observable('Person 2'), role: 'Accounts' },
    { name: ko.observable('Person 3'), role: 'Admin' }
  ]);
};

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

Comment: Was adding my answer when you submitted yours. :)

Comment: Appreciate the edit! Looks much better as a proper blockquote.

Comment: Thanks very much for the reply - I thought I was doing something wrong, but I can now see that's correct behaviour. I wrote this ultra-simple example to demonstrate the problem, but in reality the observableArray comes as JSON from the server. Is there a recommended way to take a JSON object, update an observableArray with that JSON data, and make one of the child fields observable?

Comment: My Knockout is a bit rusty, but you could probably lean on the mapping plugin (http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html) for that. Something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/rxbrw8Lb/ That empty object in the second argument to fromJS is where you'd tweak your mapping options.